# How do I debug my iOS app with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I started building my first iOS app and I am trying to debug it. I set a break point on my viewDidLoad() function (line 14) like so:
[image]

When I run the app and the get the ViewController to load, my debugger view opens in xcode but I am getting this (what looks like assembly code) view.
[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to view the debugger in my Swift code and be able to step through it in Swift. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually have any code - all you have is calls to the super class methods and you don't have the source code for that so all the debugger can show is the compiled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.

Debug > Debug Workflow > "Always Show Disassembly" was checked off. Unchecking this now shows my source code when debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the breakpoint on a line of code inside the method and not the call to the super class.
Then you'll be able to analyze variables at the breakpoint.